# prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) not called in Xcode 9 b6 on iOS 11

Tags: xcode, ios11

I just downloaded the XCode 9 Beta 6 and compiled our app without any problems, but somehow the method prepare for segue method is not called when presenting a view controller modally via a segue.

I didn't changed anything and it still works on iOS 10. Has anyone else experienced this as well?

For completeness here is some code which is not called anymore:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destination as? EventResponderSuccessViewController {
        viewController.event = event
    } else if let viewController = segue.destination as? EventResponderPaymentVerifiedController {
        viewController.event = event
    }
}
```

And two settings of not called segues:

[image: With Identifier]

[image: Without Identifier]

Comment: FYI, doing a "present modally" with "cross dissolve" like you've shared with us works fine (`prepare(for:sender:)` was called fine) with Xcode 9b6 & iOS 11. So it makes me suspect that either the base class for the presenting view controller isn't what you think it is, or the base class for the presented view controller isn't. Perhaps create new test project with this sort of segue and confirm whether it's something in your current project or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a clean build solved this for me in the end.